# Best practice for delaying jobs

Tags: php, message-queue

I have a system in PHP that works like a booking system.
Once a booking is confirmed there are a total of 7 emails/sms that needs to be send. The times of when they need to be send are already known.

For example, 24h before the bookingdate, a email goes out.

Right now we have a cron checking if it is 24h< and the 24h email didnt go out yet, it shoots a job into the queue and the job tries to send the email, if it fails it retries etc..

**How am I supposed to get a better grip on my notifications and be able to turn a single notification off or edit the content of the notification for that single booking? I am using a job-worker system that sends the notifications, I can only send them in the queue, when they are ready to be sent.**

I was thinking of creating a db table called `planned_notifications` with all the content in it, a reference to the booking_id, and a send_after column

I can then remove a row in this table if I dont want the notification to be sent, or I can edit the content in this table to change the content of the notification

A cron is in place to take rows from the `planned_notification` table into the queue system.

I am probably not the first with this problem and am looking to get some info on 'best practices' for this type of problem

Comment: Sounds like it's working.  Is it causing any problems?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to clarify what you specifically have a query about?  This is not really an answerable question as worded.

Comment: Hi @maple_shaft, I edited the question with some more context, I hope this makes it more clear

Comment: @CandiedOrange , During development it is hard for us to track what happends and if the notification has been put into the queue correctly, we want to get more insight in WHAT is going out WHEN, since we have a lot of settings that tell if something should get send or not and to whom

Comment: When editing a notification, are you simply wanting the edit to affect all pending notifications or looking to customize individual notifications?

Comment: @Mazzy I further edited your question to exemplify the leading question.  The Q&A format of this site just isn't good for getting general design advice.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Just the individual ones: example: someone books a trip with us, we have special days/events where notifications aren't neccesary since we will be waiting for the bookers on the location, we have a backoffice who can sit and turn them off or change them accordingly

Comment: @maple_shaft Thanks Maple, I appreciate that, I see it is much more clearer now, I will try to do the same with my future questions!

Comment: I can understand wanting to have manual control of this process.  But I encourage you to consider making as much of it automatic as you can.  Is there anywhere in the system where business logic can be applied to at least resolve the more mundane needs to modify notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two main concerns here in high level design are essentially, the messaging from one or more software components to other software components, and flexible scheduling of jobs based on the age of a message event.

Some important considerations to make here are that you don't want to intermix what MQ messaging provides your system with scheduling or time sensitive events.  So how do we start?

### Create a Component Diagram

This will help you visualize and realize the various independent software components at play in your system.  Keeping in mind that components should be loosely coupled with each other and independently testable, you should be able to identify what components belong.  They should not take on more responsibility in the system than what is necessary.

For instance, a Booking? component should have the responsibility of creating and updating `planned_notifications`, however is taking on too much responsibility by also sending notifications and owning the business logic of when it is appropriate to send.

## Component Interactions

When you decide on MQ Messaging, realize it is the glue that will tie your components together.  In your diagram you can connect various components with *Interactions*, in this case the SMS/Email component can be sent a message that contains the details of the message to send, but it is important for SMS/Email component to not contain the business logic for determination of when a message should be sent.

It looks like your thoughts are already correct here.  You shouldn't use MQ for data persistence. The need for a table is important.

## High Level Design

If I were designing this system with this limited information upfront.  I would create a booking component that schedules planned notifications in a table.  The Scheduler component will contain a process that wakes up at regular intervals and identifies notifications to be sent, then formulating MQ messages with the details for the messages to be sent to a queue.  A Notification component will read from the queue and own the responsibility for sending the notification.

In addition to this, some important things to consider are proper Exception Management.  Any number of things can go wrong when sending an SMS or email, so you may want to consider an Acknowledgement queue that the Notification component can asynchronously provide a Success or Failure update message.  Another software component may want to read these acknowledgment messages and update the database or logs accordingly.